# Leaflet.editable show coords in tooltip for vertex

Tags: java, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using leaflet.editable to modify geoJSON objects and I would like to show a tooltip for the vertices with the gps coords in it. Is there a way to modify the vertices to set the tooltip and possibly even the icon used?

Comment: My favourite draw library is: https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman But what tooltip do you mean? And while drawing or if it is drawed. And what are vertices for you (the polyline while drawing?) and which icon?

Comment: I've looked at that one... it's essentially the same.  I'm talking about the vertices visible when the polygon (or line) is editable.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite to default enableEdit function for every layertype: (You have to programm by yourself, that the tooltips showing always!)

```
L.Polygon.prototype.enableEdit = function (map) {
    if (!this.editor) this.createEditor(map);
    this.editor.enable();
    this.editor.editLayer.eachLayer(function(layer){layer.bindTooltip(""+layer.getLatLng()).openTooltip(); });
    return this.editor;
}
```

The fastest way to change the icon, is to change the css style:

```
.leaflet-div-icon {
    background: #c72e2e; //maybe you have to add !important
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Also you can try to change the VertexIcon https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable/blob/bffa390d3f4caaeb74f74ceba460adc8f283d340/src/Leaflet.Editable.js#L439